# How to return List of objects containing aggregated (rising) sum of following elements with C# Enumerable.Aggregate method?

Tags: c#, algorithm, aggregate, ienumerable

I have class ObjectA with property called *Value*.

I have also class ObjectB with property called *Sum*.

Then I have List<ObjectA> listA.

**How to return List<ObjectB> listB from C# Enumerable.Aggregate method, where property *Sum* of every following ObjectB is the (rising) aggregated sum of properties *Value* from List<ObjectA>?**

EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:

IN: List of ObjectA with following properties Value {1,2,3,4,5,6}

OUT: List of ObjectB with following properties Sum {1,3,6,10,15,21}

Comment: Why do you want to use `Aggregate` for this? It sounds kind of like saying, "How can I cut a board using a hammer?"

Comment: StackOverflow is no a code writing nor homework service. Please show what you have attempted (in C# code) and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Don't. Use Select or a loop instead.

Long answer:

`Aggregate` is intended for cases where you *start* with a list of values, but want to end up with a single value. You're trying to end up with another collection, with one value for each input.

That's not to say it can't be done. Just for academic purposes, let's look at some of the patterns you could use. I'm going to simplify the problem to just use integers instead of `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`.

This is probably the most "pure" approach, in the sense that the delegate you pass to Aggregate has no side-effects.

```
var values = new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
var sums = values.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), (previous, next) => previous.Append(previous.LastOrDefault() + next)).ToList();
```

However, this *probably* has `O(n²)` complexity because you're calling `LastOrDefault()` on `IEnumerable<>`s constructed by chaining `Append` calls together. It might be preferable to accept a little impurity by closing over a running total variable.

```
var values = new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
int runningTotal = 0;
var sums = values.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), (previous, next) => previous.Append(runningTotal += next)).ToList();
```

But if we're willing to track state that way, things could be much simpler by just using `Select` instead of `Aggregate`:

```
int runningTotal = 0;
var sums = values.Select(next => runningTotal += next).ToList();
```

And of course, purists would say that functional syntax like LINQ statements shouldn't have side-effects. It might be clearer to just build out a new list with a more imperative-style foreach loop.

```
var values = new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
var sums = new List<int>();
int runningTotal = 0;
foreach(var next in values)
{
    runningTotal += next;
    sums.Add(runningTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `Aggregate` in the following way:

```
var objectBs = objectAs
    .Aggregate<ObjectA, IEnumerable<ObjectB>>(
        Enumerable.Empty<ObjectB>(), 
        (objectBs, objectA) => objectBs.Append(new ObjectB
        {
            Sum = (objectBs.LastOrDefault()?.Sum ?? 0) + objectA.Value
        }));
```

But this hard to read for people (I personally do). Alternatively, write it with a for loop:

```
var listOfObjectBs = new List<ObjectB>
{
    new ObjectB
    {
        Sum = objectAs.First().Value
    }
};

for (var i = 1; i < objectAs.Count; i++)
{
    listOfObjectBs.Add(new ObjectB
    {
        Sum = listOfObjectBs[i - 1].Sum + objectAs[i].Value
    });
}
```